# Subdomain with WWW not secured even with a SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have requested a certificate in AWS Certificate Manager for its Domain Name and its Subdomain and it's already issued.

```
example.com
*.example.com
```

I have check each domain and subdomain with www and with non-www

```
https://www.example.com // secured
https://example.com // secured

https://www.subdomain.example.com // not secured
https://subdomain.example.com // secured
```

I have use S3 bucket for Static Web Hosting and CloudFront for the app.

What is the reason for this?
Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate would need to include:

```
example.com
*.example.com
*.subdomain.example.com
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks

Comment: Can we add this `*.*.example.com` to request certificate in AWS? @Matt

Comment: I am not too sure about that sorry - You can try it out and see if it works?

Comment: @RichardVergis did u get this working?

Comment: it does work, but lets say i have more  subdomains being added as the time goes by. Is there a way to have a wildcard instead of recreating new certs and changing them? @RichardVergis

Comment: I think you can do that as well. I have not tried that though. You can test it @sem10